# Compound words in English

Tags: word-usage

To what extent compound words are appropriate in English? Are the "onthedownburninghouseresting", "firesurrounded" valid words in English?

Comment: The longest **valid** compound word I know is *absentmindedness*. The two from you are just out of the world ;)

Comment: Did you find these words in a dictionary or some other reference?

Comment: Please don't crosspost between ELL and ELU, especially without telling anyone you're doing so.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200432/compound-words-limitation

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted to ELU, and we should only have one copy of a question active at a given time.

Answer (score 1):

In English, compound nouns consisting of more than two words are typically hyphenated.

**If you ask the man-on-the-street...**

does not mean

**If you ask the man on the street...**

Man-on-the-street means "the average Joe" or "the average guy".  "The man on the street" means "the man who is on the roadway."

There are a handful of such words. But it's also possible to create an almost infinite number of quasi-neologisms by yoking the words in a descriptive phrase in that same manner.

```
Some women are hat-wearers and some are not.    

He always had a caught-in-the-act-look on his face.
```

or alternatively, a compound adjective:

```
He always had a caught-in-the-act look on his face.
```

Comment: Should I hyphenate only those words that include articles and prepositions?

Comment: See the answer for the answer.